# CVS I have add a file in the wrong place? Should I remove it?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I work on two CVS branches simultaneously. And now I have added a file in branch_1 instead of branch_2. How to "UNDO" the `cvs add` operation. Actually, does it change something on repository, or just locally in `CVS` directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `cvs remove` command.

I think that if you **haven't committed yet**, your addition/removal won't even appear in the repo history, otherwise you will see it but the file won't be there anymore.

And if you **haven't committed**, a `cvs update -C` should do the trick also, as the `cvs add` command marks files for addition but they are really added with the next commit.

Comment: So `cvs remove` is the solution or no need to worry at all, as no change is being done on repository with `cvs add`? I guess the second one!

Comment: Yes absolutely, `cvs remove` is the solution :) The `cvs add` operation will not finish until a `cvs commit` is done. But be aware that the file itself will be erased from your disk! Take a backup copy before! :)

Comment: But if `cvs add` does not change anything on repository, than why I need to `cvs remove` it?

Comment: What is really needed here is to remove the new entry from the `CVS/Entries` file. Both commands will do the job as long as you haven't committed yet... the only difference being that `remove` will actually delete the file.

Comment: Also I could not find what is `cvs update -C` doing? -C option is for what?

Comment: `cvs update -C` will bring your working copy up-to-date, discarding **all your uncommitted changes**. So use it with caution ;-) (BTW, if you are using WinCVS, the option is called _Get the clean copy_ in the _Update settings_ tab)

Comment: But if it is newly added file, what should I understand by saying "Get the clean copy"?

Comment: That you will get a clean copy of the `CVS/Entries` file... :)